# Adding custom button in wordpress visual editor

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to add background image(post) to my wordpress visual editor, i am able to insert content button but when i am trying to insert background-image button then its inserting 'browse' in post but i want that when i click on that button it should browse the image and insert it as the background image of the post.

The code that i have written is

/*--------php file----------*/

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_button');

function my_button() {
    global $typenow;
    // check user permissions
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_posts') && !current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
    return;
    }
    // verify the post type
    if( ! in_array( $typenow, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) )
        return;
    // check if WYSIWYG is enabled
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "add_custombutton_plugin");
        add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_custom_button');
    }
}

function add_custombutton_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['custom_button'] = plugins_url( '/text-button.js', __FILE__ ); // CHANGE THE BUTTON SCRIPT HERE
    return $plugin_array;
}

function register_custom_button($buttons) {
   array_push($buttons, "custom_button");
   return $buttons;
}
```

/*-------js file------*/

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('custom_button', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton( 'custom_button', {
            text: 'My test button',
            icon: false,
            onclick: function() {
                editor.insertContent('<input type="file">');
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Please help me out .